# Opening PHP files in vim gives me error: E108: No such variable: "b:current_syntax"

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin

I'm running cygwin on my Windows box, and everytime I open up a php file using vim, i get this error:

```
sendgrid-test.php" 7L, 46C
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/syntax/php.vim:
line  112:
E108: No such variable: "b:current_syntax"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The file opens just fine, but the highlighting is very messed up, it's difficult to get in there and code.  I'm not sure where to start so that I can ensure vim has proper syntaxing for PHP on this machine.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks,
Arie

Comment: Did you try just deleting the line 112 from the file mentioned? It might just work.

Comment: The file syntax/php.vim sources other syntax files and apparently expects b:current_syntax to have been set by one of them, syntax/sql.vim, I think.  I don't see that error so I wonder if some files are missing from your installation.  Try executing ":scriptnames". Towards the bottom of that list you should see /usr/share/vim/syntax/php.vim followed by .../html.vim, .../javascript.vim, .../vb.vim, .../css.vim, .../sql.vim and .../sqloracle.vim. At least that's what I see.

Comment: Here is the result of running :scriptnames: : /usr/share/vim/vimrc                                                              
  2: /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/plugin/matchparen.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/syntax/php.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/syntax/html.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/syntax/javascript.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/syntax/vb.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/syntax/css.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/syntax/sql.vim

Comment: Which version of Vim? (:version within Vim, or vim --version on the command line)

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled May 14 2007 16:29:51)

Comment: Very much outdated. If you're using cygwin, you should be able to re-run the cygwin installer and it will update Vim (and probably a lot of other stuff).

Comment: Well, cygwin was installed with MobaSSH which included vim.  I tried installed cygwin with the installer, but alas it didn't change anything.

Comment: As Heptite pointed out, that's a pretty old version of Vim and it's hard to say what bugs may have existed then and have since been fixed. My Cygwin installation is pretty up to date and it's using Vim 7.3.646 compiled Aug 31 2012. If I start it as `vim -N -u NONE`, execute `:filetype plugin indent on`, `:syntax on` and `:e foo.php`, I don't get any errors. You could debug your current installation using `-V` with a file or using the `:debug` command, but that's pretty tedious, especially if you don't know what you're looking for or what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `syntax/sql.vim` script, which `syntax/php.vim` is including. As others have pointed out in the comments, you Vim installation is pretty outdated, so an update might fix things already.

To just pragmatically get rid of the error, create a `~/.vim/syntax/sql.vim` file with just

```
:let b:current_syntax = 'sql'
```

in it, or change the `:unlet` at line 112 to `:unlet!`.